# Building and using OpenCV as a static library with Ffmpeg

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, static, ffmpeg

I'm trying write an OpenCV application. I've statically built OpenCV from source as I don't want dll files and my project compiles as long as I don't use `cv::VideoCapture`, in which case I get a link error `LNK2019` unresolved external symbol.

I think this is because the `cv::VideoCapture` uses ffmpeg to work with video, which, because of it's license, cannot be statically linked in my project. I would be ok with linking the ffmpeg dynamically but I'm having trouble doing this. There is a `opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll` file in the `%OpenCV_DIR%\bin` folder, but I'm clueless about how to dynamically link it to my project. Usually I have `.lib` files that come with the `.dll` but I can't find them anywhere.

Is it possible to statically link OpenCV and dynamically link ffmpeg, and how should I go about doing this?

Additional info:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2015
- OpenCV 3.1.0 x64 build

Comment: Build ffmpeg dynamically, build opencv and link with ffmpeg just built?

Comment: May be this issue would help you https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5920

Comment: @stijn How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If I'd know I'd create a full answer :] Building ffmpeg is documented so should be easy, getting opencv to link with your own ffmpeg might require some cmake wizardry or manual editing of VS project files

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. I was wrong thinking I needed ffmpeg to get it working. The problem I had was solved by adding `vfw32.lib` to the library dependencies in Visual Studio.